# Java: clicking on button->start new frame

Tags: java

I am new to Java.

I made a new NewJFrame.java.

In my current frame, i have a button, how can i link it to NewJFrame.java?

Comment: Please post the code that you have written.

Comment: I agree with keuleJ, look at the Swing Tutorial; this should have enough answers that you can find what you need!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add an event handler to this button and in it you create and show NewJFrame.

Edited: This is a basic example [how to make a JFrame](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/frame.html):

```
//1. Create the frame.
JFrame frame = new JFrame("FrameDemo");

//2. Optional: What happens when the frame closes?
frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

//3. Create components and put them in the frame.
//...create emptyLabel...
frame.getContentPane().add(emptyLabel, BorderLayout.CENTER);

//4. Size the frame.
frame.pack();

//5. Show it.
frame.setVisible(true);
```

Please RTFM.

Comment: i have an event handler to this button, show.NewJFrame(); wont work

Comment: Check two things:
1. Make sure your event handler is called (write something to console).

Comment: 2. Check that your NewJFrame is working on it's own. Is this a normal JFrame or some your extended version?